# Wordpress server move issue

Tags: wordpress

I tried to move a wordpress page from my local server to a public one.

I uploaded the files via ftp, changed the wp-config.php file with the data of the online server, exported the mysql database tables and past them into the online db, and last I changed the urls in the wp_options table.

Unfortunately the result is "nothing". Meaning before I changed the wp-config.php file it said something like DATABASE Error but now not even an error.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** from comments: the error message when error reporting is enabled is:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for testfunktion(), called in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 6 and defined in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined variable: variable in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 9 20 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/wp-config.php on line 27

Here my wp-config.php file without the commentaries:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'AAA');

define('DB_USER', 'BBB');

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'CCC');

define('DB_HOST', ‘DDD.com');

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');


define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 */
define('AUTH_KEY',         'XXXX');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'YYYY');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'DDDD');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'JJJJ');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'LLLL');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'OOOO');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'PPPP');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'UUUU');

/**#@-*/

$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

define('WPLANG', 'de_DE');

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Comment: Sounds like a parser error or some other fatal error. Turn on error reporting and post the errors you see.

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 1 for testfunktion(), called in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 6 and defined in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined variable: variable in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 9 20 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/wp-config.php on line 27

Comment: I added an answer. Post your wp-config.php **without your host, username, password, or database name**, and I may be able to help you more.

Comment: Doesn't the DB_HOST need the protocol "http://" ? because that's the only ":" in that line. And the wp-config.php without my host, username, password, or database name would be the wp-config-sample.php

Comment: No. DB_HOST is the host name. The `http://` is a *protocol* that precedes the host name. Take that out and make sure you have closed all of your `'` and `"` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, you made a typo in `wp-config.php` at line 27 or possibly in the line before. Fix that first, and probably the other errors will go away on their own.

Comment: There was an "http://" in front of the server.
Now, without it gives me:

Warning: Missing argument 1 for testfunktion(), called in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 6 and defined in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 8 Notice: Undefined variable: variable in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/index.php on line 9 20 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /mnt/webn/e3/40/54063140/htdocs/wp-config.php on line 30

Comment: Well, you have a typo, most likely a missing `'`, `"`, or `.`. As I said above, post your wp-config.php **without your host, username, password, or database name**, and I may be able to help you more.

Comment: I found the ' in front of the DB_Host

Comment: So, did that resolve your problems? You should have something like `define('DB_HOST', 'mydomain.com');`